# Oracle PLSQL - Commit only database link

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to commit only the data inserted/updated on a table through a database link and **not** the data of the current session?  Or are they considered one and the same?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO main_database.main_table(value1, value2)
VALUES (1 , 2)

INSERT INTO database.table@database_link(value3, value4)
VALUES (3 , 4)
```

And do a commit for only the database link table?

Background on why I would want to do this:
The main database is for (multiple) records while the database link is for (monetary) transactions (processed on a separate server).  I want to update the records first to check to see if any of the constraints fail, but not commit the data until the transaction is complete.  If the transaction fails, I want to rollback the records to save me the effort of deleting/undoing inserts/updates which could get messy.

I am assuming there is not but I am hoping that there is a way.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the context?  You could create a savepoint between the two statements, rollback to the savepoint, and then commit.  But that assumes that there are no uncommitted statements before the first statement and that you can neatly separate the two strands of work.  Plus, if you know that you always want to commit the remote changes, it would make more sense to just issue an explicit commit after the first statement.

Comment: Basically, the answer is no.  But I'm struggling to understand what you would want to do this for.  Can you give us a bit more information, please?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Read - `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION pragma` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure proc_1 ( i IN number )
as
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test_table@remote_sid (id, description)
    VALUES (i, 'Description for ' || i);
  COMMIT;
END;
/

create or replace procedure proc_base ( i IN number )
as
begin
  insert into local_tab (id) values (i);
  proc_1( i );
  rollback;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

If the insert is in a pl/SQL then you can run the first insert in an autonomous transaction, but in the absence of other functionality that's little different than insert....; commit; insert...

Comment: I apologize, this is in PLSQL.  Could you give an example of an autonomous transaction?

Comment: I posted a sample pl/sql below, which might work for you, try it